# Прорвёмся — этимология слова

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошло выражение "прорвёмся"?

Comment: "Прорвёмся" — это не термин, а глагол.

Answer (score 2):

[**Прорваться**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/190442) — многозначное слово. У Ожегова одним из его значений является такое:
**4.** Силой проложить себе путь откуда-нибудь. *Прорваться из окружения.*

В других словарях:
преодолевая сопротивление, силой проложить себе путь;
разрушая препятствие, проходить, вырываться;
преодолевая сопротивление, двигаться, идти куда-либо;
проникать, проходить сквозь какую-либо преграду.

В этом значении слово начали использовать давно.
Мы непременно найдем свободное место, а если нет, то силою прорвемся. [Ф. В. Булгарин. Димитрий Самозванец (1830)]

Происходит от глагола [**рвать**](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).
В этимологическом словаре М. Шанского: общеславянское; родственно др.-инд. *rávati* «дробит, разбивает», лат. *ruere* «раскалывать, разрывать».
В этимологическом словаре М. Фасмера: р̀ве̑м се «бороться», р̀вати «напрягаться».

*Прорвёмся* — это укороченное, экспрессивное от "мы прорвёмся" или "давай прорвёмся".

[В. В. Иванов. Бронепоезд № 14.69](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=650243&p=74) (1922):

> — Прорвемся... к черту!.. Нам никаких командований... Нам плевать!..
> Но так же, как и вчера, версту за верстой, как Обаб пищу, торопливо и жадно хватал бронепоезд — и не насыщался. Так же мелькали будки стрелочников, и так же, забитый полями, ветром и морем, жил на том конце рельсов непонятный и страшный в молчании город.
> — Прорвемся, — выхаркивал полковник и бежал к машинисту.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, слово пришло из военной риторики (что неудивительно при всеобщей воинской обязанности), связанной с **прорывом** позиций (рядов, укреплений, обороны, блокады) противника и прохождением сквозь них. Слово выражает надежду, что единомышленники рано или поздно добьются успеха или выхода из трудной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

После @РиммаМихайлова мне совершенно расхотелось писать свой ответ, там почти все сказали. Кроме разве что одной вещи. Мне бы хотелось явным образом сформулировать, что слово в данном значении не обязательно порождено военной тематикой. @Alex_ander тут, похоже, немного ошибается.

Например, прорваться "сквозь заносы" или "сквозь льды" известны довольно давно, а "прорваться" у военных не могло иметь широкого распространения до появления накануне Первой Мировой современного боевого порядка "сплошной фронт".